# Any way to install executable along with library via go get?

Tags: go, binary, installation, package, executable

It took me sometime to have some basic understandings of Go's package structure & came up with this in my project:

> ```
> </github.com/myproject/demo/
> ▸ config/
> ▸ crypto/
> ▸ demo/
>     executable.go
>   deps.go
>   LICENSE
>   README.md
>   demo.go
> ```

I can now have the same name for the libary & binary, but not in the way I want. Binary executable has to be installed separately via go get like "go get github.com/myproject/demo/demo", is there anyway to install the binary executable via single go get like "go get github.com/myproject/demo"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

```
go get github.com/myproject/demo/...
```

The ellipsis (...) means all sub directories

I'm pretty sure this will install all executables and libraries in your "demo" repository

Comment: Wah, didn't know a trick like this. Work pretty well. But is there any thing I can add/config to achieve the same goal in the standard way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'standard way"  meaning, someone does go get github.com/myproject/demo and gets multiple executables?  nope, no way to do that that I'm aware of

Comment: Exactly, thought it could be (& it really should) configured to achieved this. But thanks anyway, the ellipsis trick is already good enough :-)